# Receiving ajax error even if record successfully created, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Problem**: Error message is displayed even if record is successfully saved. Basically, error message is displayed no matter if I input correct data or incorrect (regarding validations).

I am using Remotipart (file upload) and Humanizer (human validation) gems together with RAILS 4.

**Form**:

```
  <%= form_for(@advertisement,:html => {:id=>"new_advertisement","data-parsley-validate" => true,:multipart => true}, remote: true ,format: :json) do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_field :name , :'data-parsley-minlength'=>3,:required => true, :class=> "reg_name",:placeholder=>t('name_in_latvian')%>

        <%= f.email_field(:email,:required => true,:placeholder=> t('email') ,:'data-validate' => '/blocked/checkemail',:id => 'email_field') %>                                

        <span><%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: false,:id=>"myfile2"%></span>

        <span><%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: false,:id=>"myfile3" %></span>



    <button type="submit" class="blue-button btn btn-default" style="width:380px !important;"><%= t('add') %></button>
```

**Controller**:

```
def create
        @code = Billing.where(:country_id=>@location.id).where(:group_name=>"add_advertisement").first

 @advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params.merge(service_ids: params[:service_ids], hour_ids: params[:hour_ids]))

  respond_to do |format|
    if @advertisement.save

         if params[:images]
             params[:images].each { |image|
                @advertisement.pictures.create(image: image)
             }
         end


          if @advertisement.paid == true
               @advertisement.update_attribute(:paid, true)
          else
               @advertisement.update_attribute(:paid, false)           
          end



      format.html  {redirect_to successful_registration_index_path}
      format.json  { render :json => @advertisement,
                    :status => :created, :location => @advertisement }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @advertisement.errors,
                    :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**Script**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#new_advertisement").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
       alert("success");

  }).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {

       alert("error");

  });
});
```

**Model:**

```
   validates :email,:phone_number, uniqueness: true   #tikai testējot new advertisement
   validates :description, length: { maximum: 200 }
   validates :description_ru, length: { maximum: 200 }
   validates :services, :length => { :minimum => 4, :message => " should be atleast 4 services selected"}
   validates :name, :email, :subname, :country_id, :region_id, :age,:phone_number, :presence => true     
   validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true, :on => :create
   validates :needs_dist, acceptance: true ,:on => :create
```

**Extraction from log file:**

```
Started POST "/lv/advertisements.json" for 85.254.76.108 at 2016-10-03 12:22:27 +0300
Processing by AdvertisementsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "advertisement"=>{"name"=>"asda", "subname"=>"dasda", "region_id"=>"4", "country_id"=>"1", "age"=>"21", "height"=>"142", "phone_number"=>"25669996" , "work1"=>"13", "work2"=>"19", "work3"=>"5", "work4"=>"8", "email"=>"gghsh@.eu", "description"=>"das da", "description_ru"=>"da das da", "terms_of_service"=>"1", "humanizer_question_id"=>"2", "humanizer_question"=>"5 reizes 2 ?", "humanizer_answer"=>"10", "identifier"=>"1235"}, "service_ids"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "10"], "paid"=>"false", "why"=>"", "authenticity_token"=>"RzTRJpPNez1u/B9VKYxyogk2tQoxonC3keUmTR7SJys=", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006abd910 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161003-699023-1ishrmf>, @original_filename="gallery-img2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"gallery-img2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000006abd8e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161003-699023-vekzaq>, @original_filename="person.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"person.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], "locale"=>"lv"}
  [1m[36mBanlist Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `banlists`.* FROM `banlists`  WHERE (ip_adress = '85.254.76.108')[0m
  [1m[35mCountry Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  `countries`.* FROM `countries`  WHERE `countries`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRegion Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `regions`.* FROM `regions`  WHERE `regions`.`country_id` = 1[0m
  [1m[35mPartner Load (0.7ms)[0m  SELECT  `partners`.* FROM `partners`  WHERE `partners`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mBilling Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `billings`.* FROM `billings`  WHERE `billings`.`country_id` = 1 AND `billings`.`group_name` = 'add_advertisement'  ORDER BY `billings`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m

  [1m[35mService Load (1.1ms)[0m  SELECT `services`.* FROM `services`  WHERE `services`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10)
  [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mAdvertisement Exists (0.8ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `advertisements`  WHERE `advertisements`.`email` = BINARY 'gghsh@.eu' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mAdvertisement Exists (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM `advertisements`  WHERE `advertisements`.`phone_number` = BINARY '25669996' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `advertisements` (`age`,  `country_id`, `created_at`, `description`, `description_ru`, `email`, `expiration`, `phone_number`, `recomend`, `region_id`, `subname`, `updated_at`, `vip_highlight`, `vip_recomend`) VALUES (21, '2', 40, 1, '2016-10-03 12:22:27', 'das da', 'da das da', 'gghsh@.eu', '2016-11-28 12:22:27', 142, '2016-10-03 12:22:27', '1235', 'asda',  '25669996', '2016-10-03 12:22:27', 4, 'dasda', '2016-10-03 12:22:27', '2016-10-03 12:22:27', '2016-10-03 12:22:27', 42, '13', '19', '5', '8')
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`confirmation_token` = 'e7711059327df946867090920f248dec09cda8542d26494379430dee7a1af233'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `users` (`confirmation_sent_at`, `confirmation_token`, `country_id`, `created_at`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `role`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-10-03 12:22:27', 'e7711059327df946867090920f248dec09cda8542d26494379430dee7a1af233', 1, '2016-10-03 12:22:27', 'gghsh@.eu', '$2a$10$3xJAdciVZZ2KMJprFHBndeLdgm0GyEWbUYLZMD/1LyOsWKmFkKX3y', 'advertisement', '2016-10-03 12:22:27')
  [1m[36mGirl Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `advertisements`.* FROM `advertisements`  WHERE `advertisements`.`user_id` = 332 LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (4.3ms)

  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  UPDATE `advertisements` SET `age` = 21,  `country_id` = 1, `created_at` = '2016-10-03 12:22:27', `description` = 'das da', `description_ru` = 'da das da', `email` = 'gghsh@.eu', `expiration` = '2016-11-28 12:22:27', `highlight` = '2016-10-03 12:22:27', `id` = 147, `identifier` = '1235', `name` = 'asda',`phone_number` = '25669996', `recomend` = '2016-10-03 12:22:27', `region_id` = 4, `subname` = 'dasda', `updated_at` = '2016-10-03 12:22:27', `user_id` = 332, `vip_highlight` = '2016-10-03 12:22:27', `vip_recomend` = '2016-10-03 12:22:27', `work1` = '13', `work2` = '19', `work3` = '5', `work4` = '8' WHERE `advertisements`.`id` = 147

  [1m[35m (0.9ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-wpmc6f.jpg'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "200x230>" '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u20161003-699023-rb3o8z'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u20161003-699023-rb3o8z'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "447x479>" '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u20161003-699023-uhtf8m'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u20161003-699023-uhtf8m'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u20161003-699023-r8mxi9'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-2x4l2u20161003-699023-r8mxi9'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/d0ac370875764ddc24c4a9c2b2c658cc20161003-699023-8zu57p.jpg'
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `pictures` (`created_at`, `girl_id`, `image_content_type`, `image_file_name`, `image_file_size`, `image_updated_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-10-03 12:22:27', 147, 'image/jpeg', 'gallery-img2.jpg', 39598, '2016-10-03 12:22:27', '2016-10-03 12:22:27')
  [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-kh3ipc.jpg'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "200x230>" '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva20161003-699023-1gkkuft'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva20161003-699023-1gkkuft'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "447x479>" '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva20161003-699023-4cfa2'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva20161003-699023-4cfa2'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; convert '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva20161003-699023-1eh3y49'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-1m2qeva20161003-699023-1eh3y49'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/8b0a44048f58988b486bdd0d245b22a820161003-699023-viagov.jpg'
  [1m[36mSQL (8.1ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `pictures` (`created_at`, `girl_id`, `image_content_type`, `image_file_name`, `image_file_size`, `image_updated_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-10-03 12:22:28', 147, 'image/jpeg', 'person.jpg', 13168, '2016-10-03 12:22:28', '2016-10-03 12:22:28')[0m
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  COMMIT
Completed 201 Created in 1196ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 23.0ms)
```

This is the only error in logs, but still advertisement is created and unfortunately error message is displayed when it shouldn't have.

**What I have tried:**

1) Removed e-mail and phone uniqueness validations - still error message

2) Disabled humanizer - still error message.

3) Double checked if submited e-mail and phone doesn't already exist in table - they don't exist in table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post the details of the error? What status code is the server returning? What is the body of the error response?

Comment: @RyanBrunner , Hi, I added full log.

Comment: I can't see an error in the console. Do you mean your own error is being displayed on the front-end?

Comment: @RichardAE, I am getting only alert error from my script. There is no any other error displayed to me.

Comment: status: 2xx is success.. returning status: :created will probably generate an error on the client side (after successfully creating the record)